# Roslyn Data flow analysis - ambiguous values for WrittenInside and Locations fields

Tags: c#, roslyn

I recently started working with Data Flow Analysis APIs provided by Roslyn and find values presented in WrittenInside field and Locations field a bit ambiguous.

Consider below code snippet in Main method

```
1. int[] lcolSample = new int[10] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
2. for (int lintCount1 = 0; lintCount1 < 10; lintCount1++)
3. {
4.     Prog1(lintCount1);
5.     int[] lcolSample1 = new int[10] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
6.     lintCount3 = lintCount3 + 100;
7.     lintCount1 = lintCount1 + 2;
8.     lcolSample[lintCount1-1] = lcolSample1[lintCount1] + 100;
9. }
```

1. If I perform DFA on for loop node,  resulting Data Flow Analysis object never shows lcolSample[] in WrittenInside field as symbol that is written inside for loop. Reason being it is declared outside the node on which Dataflow analysis is performed.  But, ReadInside field shows this symbol.  Is there any way to know all the symbols that are modified/written inside a given node even though they are declared outside the node on which DFA is performed?
2. Variable lintCount1 is written twice (statement 2 and 7) and read twice.  Locations property on lintCount1 shows only the place where it is declared (statement 2).  Is there a way to find all the locations in which lintCount1 is written?  Find all references of that symbol would give all the locations where the symbol is used, but I require the locations where it is written but not read.

This is my first question on this forum.  Please ask for any other details if information provided above is not sufficient.  Thanks in advance..

Comment: `lcolSample` is never written inside the loop. However, it is read on line 8.

Comment: Mutating the object referred to by a variable is not the same as modifying the variable.

Comment: @JoshVarty - sorry.. my mistake.. edited line 8 - it was meant to be like this

Comment: @SLaks - Thanks for the reply.. is there a way to identify such references?

Comment: @SreenathKaranam: What do you mean?

Comment: @SLaks: as you mentioned, object referred to by lcolSample is modified above inside for loop.  I was asking if it is possible to identify  such references i.e. identify that lcolSample is being modified as the object it refers to is being written inside block/loop.  Though the same object can be referred by multiple variables, identifying variable referring to object at declaration time would be sufficient or identify all the variables in scope that refer to object being modified..

Comment: @SreenathKaranam: How do you propose to determine what operations modify an arbitrary object? This is equivalent to the halting problem.

Comment: @SLaks: just googled for halting problem - din't know that I was asking for solution to such a scary problem :) will try some other way some other day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Data Flow Analysis object never shows lcolSample[] in WrittenInside field as symbol that is written inside for loop

Yes, because that symbol is not written inside the loop (i.e. there is no `lcolSample = whatever` there). An element of the array represented by the `lcolSample` symbol is written in the loop, which is very different. I don't know how to find such writes using Roslyn's data flow analysis.

> Locations property on lintCount1 shows only the place where it is declared (statement 2). Is there a way to find all the locations in which lintCount1 is written?

The `DataFlowAnalysis` object only gives you the symbols, accessing their `Location`s doesn't make much sense (because that location has nothing to do with the data flow analysis).

To me, both your questions sound like reasonable feature requests, you might want to make them [on the Roslyn repo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).